# Compute Summation on Multiple Aspects

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that is similar to the following picture. Every time an emission is reported, a row is inserted to the table. The `total` column is just the addition of `CO` and `CO2` columns. There can be multiple rows for any city on a particular date. The following table represents data for only two dates and three different cities.

[image: Sample database]

For each date, I need to compute totals for `CO`, `CO2`, and `total` columns for each city, then calculate the subtotal of those cities for that date. Finally, combine those subtotals into a grand total. The following picture represents the result I am trying to achieve,

[image: Expected result]

In addition to that, I also need to keep a couple of filters such as result for a certain date range or a certain country, etc. I am planning to query rows and loop over them to compute the summations at the PHP end. This approach is questionable as it does not seem very efficient for a large volume of data. I was wondering if there is any efficient way of doing this type of computation, maybe using complex GROUP BY or temporary table/view at the MySQL end. Please suggest any better way to do it for a table that may grow up to a few millions of rows. Let me also include an array representation of the sample data for convenience,

```php
$sample = [
    ['id', 'date', 'country', 'city', 'CO', 'CO2', 'total'],
    [1, '2020-07-13', 'US', 'Scarsdale', 5, 10, 15],
    [2, '2020-07-13', 'US', 'Scarsdale', 10, 10, 20],
    [3, '2020-07-13', 'US', 'SF', 5, 15, 20],
    [4, '2020-07-13', 'US', 'SF', 15, 25, 40],
    [5, '2020-07-13', 'UK', 'London', 10, 15, 25],
    [6, '2020-07-12', 'UK', 'London', 10, 20, 30],
    [7, '2020-07-12', 'UK', 'London', 5, 5, 10],
    [8, '2020-07-12', 'US', 'SF', 10, 20, 30],
    [9, '2020-07-12', 'US', 'Scarsdale', 5, 5, 10],
];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `WITH ROLLUP`...

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you very much. This will do the trick. I am looking into it.